# Microsoft Access: how to choose name for event procedure?

Tags: vba, ms-access, event-handling

Is it possible to choose name for VBA event procedure within Microsoft Access (during design time), rather than use automatically assigned by system? For example, 'automatic' name of handler for event `Before Insert` in the form is `Form_BeforeInsert`; I'd like to choose something else. Similar problem for field value (to be returned by user function) can be solved by assigning `=myFuncName(param_list)` in the property sheet for the given field, but such approach doesn't work for event procedure. The case of event procedure looks harder because such procedure can accept some parameter(s) which value is afterward used by by system: e.g.,  `Before Insert` handler requires parameter `cancel`, and system could reject insertion in the candler sets it to `true` (or 1).

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you really can't. To use event procedures, you must adhere to the source interface's definition. Otherwise, VBA wouldn't know that it's an event procedure to run when an event is raised.

One option to consider is to delegate the work to your own procedure:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
  DoMyThing Cancel
End Sub

Private Sub DoMything(Cancel As Integer)
  'Doing my thing
End Sub
```

Comment: This, many thanks for an answer, I also think it is impossible as well. However, it is possible to set event handler dynamically (in VBA), simply set the string with the handler name to the handler (e.g. to `MyForm.onBeforeInsert`) property!

Comment: Indeed but those are not really "events". For example, it will not pass among any of the arguments, especially `Cancel` parameter. In those cases, one would have to use `DoCmd.CancelEvent` but that's too loosey-goosey for me since we don't control which event it's cancelling (since there can be events fired by other events).

Comment: If you give the control on a form a name, (as opposed to text15), then at least the event stubs  do take on the same name as the control with the "event" part added. So, you do have some control here.